# How to send/transfer/moving files between servers programmatically without scp or rsyn commandc?

Tags: node.js, file, scala

Is there a way to copy/send/transfer files from one server to another programmatically (using nodejs/scala/python) without SCP or RSYNC ?

Comment: HTTP, FTP, your own protocol - the answers are endless. Is there a specific reason that you don't want to use scp/rsync?

Comment: right, how about 'socket' ? well i want to make this transfer files become scalable. I'm using scp command executed from nodejs, but it becomes troublesome when i set up more servers and concurrent files per server.

What do you think about using socket for transfer files ? Is it scalable and reliable ?

Comment: Do you mean `socket.io`? Sure, you can use anything! There's a package called [delivery](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/02/11/12-pushing-files-to-the-browser-using-deliveryjs-socketio-and-nodejs/) which helps using socket.io to send files.